# Notes : Is there any good tool to export design elements, especially for XPages and the custom control to write the design spec document?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I created lots of XPages and the custom control in new application. Then, I need to write the design spec documents. Is there any good to help it? "Design synopsis" menu in Notes seems not to export XPages design information.

Comment: Please provide sample output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect XPages to an on disk project (ODP - see the help for that), you get a directory with design elements. XPages and controls are XML files, so you could use xslt to report on them.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If your business logic is in Java, you can generate a Javadoc of the classes https://www.intec.co.uk/generating-javadocs-for-xpages-applications/.